# How to run tasks after closing app with onStop()?

Tags: java, android, class

I am currently experimenting with Android I was wondering how i can make postDelayed run after I hit the home button?

Using handler I am able to make the postDelayed run every minute so that a integer is increased by one, but I want the integer to keep increasing even after I leave the app by pressing the home button.

Is there solution to my problem?

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` (not great) or a `Service` (better)

Comment: Also, you can use `AlarmManeger` to start your `Service` in a specific time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManeger` to start your `Service` in a specific time. Here is an example with `NotificationService`:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Setting intent");
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);

Log.i(TAG, "Setting pendingIntent");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Log.i(TAG, "Setting alarm");
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Have not tried it yet, but as soon as i find to test i will try it.